How to compute Projection matrices with Uncalibrated Stereo using OpenCV
I am using stereoRectifyUncalibrated() method which generates two homography matrices H1 and H2 for image rectification. I have checked both H1 and H2 by displaying the results of the rectified images and seems good. However, I now need to compute the new rectified P1 and P2 matrices and thereafter the new Q matrix for 3D projection.
Here comes the issue: the rectification matrices R1 and R2 derived from R = invK * H * K is not a true rotation (R.T *R != Identity AND det R =1)
I am not able to compute the new projection centres pertaining to the Q matrix based on the computed homographies.
To put it very simple, how to compute the new projection matrices P1, P2 and Q given camera intrinsics K1 and K2 , homographies H1, H2 computed above? I do also have R|t , the rototransformation from the stereo setup. The idea is to absolutely use uncalibrated stereo and NOT the stereoRectify function.
rectified images
K1 =np.float64( [[1.60131026e+03 0.00000000e+00 2.29260947e+02]
                 [0.00000000e+00 1.60048000e+03 2.69560291e+02]
                 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]])

K2 = np.float64([[1.58091430e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 2.38226966e+02]
                [0.00000000e+00, 1.57954960e+03, 2.74416747e+02]
                [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
##### Homography obtained from stereoRectifyUncalibrated
H1 = np.float64([[ 1.36739605e-01, -4.77489851e-04,  1.60414174e+00],
        [-2.40705789e-03,  1.40873271e-01,  6.98556222e-01],
        [-1.09592343e-05,  4.94715331e-07,  1.45032665e-01]])

H2 = np.float64([[ 1.01903668e+00,  1.78944538e-02, -1.02759916e+01],
        [ 8.13736635e-03,  1.00029706e+00, -2.03989019e+00],
        [ 8.02963317e-05,  1.41001696e-06,  9.80357971e-01]])

R1 = np.linalg.inv(K1) @ H1 @ K1
R2 = np.linalg.inv(K2) @ H2 @ K2

stereoMapL = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(K1, distL, R1, K1, grayL.shape[::-1], cv2.CV_32FC1) 
stereoMapR = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(K2, distR, R2, K2, grayR.shape[::-1], cv2.CV_32FC1)

rectified_left = cv2.remap(grayL, stereoMapL[0], stereoMapL[1], cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
rectified_right = cv2.remap(grayR, stereoMapR[0], stereoMapR[1], cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

ocv_rectified = cv2.hconcat([rectified_left, rectified_right])
for p in range(30):
    ocv_rectified = cv2.line(ocv_rectified, pt1=(0, p * 25), pt2=(480*2, p * 25), color=(255, 0, 255))

cv2.namedWindow("Warped Classic OCV")  # Create window with freedom of dimensions
cv2.imshow("Warped Classic OCV", ocv_rectified)
key = cv2.waitKey()

retL_st, cornersL_st = cv2.findChessboardCornersSB(rectified_left, chessboardSize, None)
retR_st, cornersR_st = cv2.findChessboardCornersSB(rectified_right, chessboardSize, None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)

if retL_st and retR_st == True:

    cornersL_st = cv2.cornerSubPix(rectified_left, cornersL_st, (7,7), (-1,-1), criteria)

    cornersR_st = cv2.cornerSubPix(rectified_right, cornersR_st, (7,7), (-1,-1), criteria)

    # Draw and display the corners
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(rectified_left, chessboardSize, cornersL_st, retL_st)
    #cv2.imshow('img left', imgL_st)
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(rectified_right, chessboardSize, cornersR_st, retR_st)
    cv2.imshow('img right', rectified_left)
    cv2.imshow('img left', rectified_right)
    cv2.waitKey()

points1 = np.asarray(cornersL_st)
points2 = np.asarray(cornersR_st)

print("points1.shape", points1.shape)


feat_l = points1.reshape(-1, points1.shape[-1])
feat_r = points2.reshape(-1, points2.shape[-1])

feat_l = np.squeeze(feat_l)
feat_r = np.squeeze(feat_r)

xc = []
yc = []
zc = []

# retL, cornersL = cv2.findChessboardCornersSB(rectified_left, chessboardSize, None)
# cornersL = cv2.cornerSubPix(rectified_left, cornersL, (7,7), (-1,-1), criteria)

# cornersL = np.squeeze(cornersL)

Tx = g_c1_c2[0][3] # baseline: -1333.26
q33 = (K1[0][2] - K2[0][2])/Tx * 10
q32 = 1/Tx 
cx =  K1[0][2]
cy = K1[1][2] 
f =  K1[0][0] 

Q1 = np.float64([[1, 0, 0, -cx],
               [0, 1, 0, -cy],
               [0, 0, 0, f],
               [0, 0, -q32 , q33]])


for j in range(np.shape(feat_l)[0]):
    disp = feat_l[j][0] - feat_r[j][0]

    # print("feat_l : {} , feat_r: {} , disp: {}".format(feat_l[j], feat_r[j], disp))

    u = feat_l[j][0]
    v = feat_l[j][1]
    p3d = Q1 @ [u , v , disp , 1]
    p3d /= p3d[3]

    # print("\n " , p3d)

    xc.append(p3d[0])
    yc.append(p3d[1])
    zc.append(p3d[2])

####################### PLOT 3D ############################
fig3 = plt.figure()
ax3 = plt.axes(projection ='3d')  

ax3.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3.set_xlabel('X')
ax3.set_zlabel('Z')
ax3.scatter(xc, yc, zc, color= 'b')
ax3.set_title('3d points in left camera')
plt.show(block=True)

}
3d projection of chessboard points

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
